# CSS force "font-size: small;" to 13px

Tags: css, font-size

how can I force the attribute "small" to a specifically size? (ex: 13px)

I'm reading data from a db and I have to display tags like this:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin: 0cm 0cm 0pt; text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: small;">Text</span></p>
```

I can't modify these tags and  works different in IE8 and FireFox so I want to force it.

Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you just specify the exact font-size you want instead of `small` then? The whole point of `small` and the other such sizes is to be relative to something the user can set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a [Standards mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standards_mode) `<!DOCTYPE>` to your document.

The font-size keywords are only implemented differently by IE in Quirks mode. Go to Standards mode and IE will behave the same as Firefox (and it fixes many other bugs too).

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
font-size: 13px;
```